# Error Handling Issue with Get-ADComputer in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am running into an error handling issue and have tried a lot of different attempts without much luck. I have a data set and am trying to compare it against AD. A machine may exist in the data set, but not in AD. I would like to retain that information in my end array, but am running into a terminating error:

> Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path .\data.csv
$cdata = @()
foreach ($data in $data) {
    foreach ($addata in (Get-ADComputer -Identity $data.Name -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object LastLogonDate)) {
        $combine = @{
            "Name" = $data.Name
            "LastPolicyRequest" = $data.LastPolicyRequest
            "LastLogonDate" =  $addata.LastLogonDate
        }
        $cdata += New-Object psobject -Property $combine
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `foreach ($data in $data)` is a bad idea, maybe you should start by using a different variable here ?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ADComputer` (and other AD cmdlets) throw this exception when you try to get an object by identity that doesn't exist. Use the `-Filter` parameter to avoid this issue. Also, don't use the same variable for item and set (`$data in $data`).

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path '.\data.csv'
foreach ($data in $csv) {
  $name = $data.Name
  foreach ($addata in (Get-ADComputer -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object LastLogonDate)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you just want to add the last logon date to those records that are present in AD you could do something like this:

```
$cdata = Import-Csv -Path '.\data.csv' |
         Select-Object Name, LastPolicyRequest, @{n='LastLogon';e={
           Get-ADComputer -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.Name)'" -Properties LastLogonDate |
             Select-Object -Expand LastLogonDate
         }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am still losing the object in the foreach loop. I would like to have it get passed onto $cdata with no data in the LastLogonDate instead of getting dropped from $cdata. If that makes sense.